# Use R to derive the parameters of a Gamma distribution

Tags: r, simulation, montecarlo, generalized-method-of-moments

I'm not 100% sure if this question should be posted here or in Mathematics Stack Exchange.

I'm a newbie in R.

The probability distribution function of Gamma distribution is given by
g(x) = 1/(b^a*Gamma(a))*x^(a-1)e^(-x/b)

I created a Monte Carlo simulation with the code below:

```
 # Number of simulations
 number_sims <- 10000

 # Samples of fixed size n = 1000
 n = 1000

 for (i in 1:n){
 gamma1 <- rgamma(10, shape=1)
 gamma2 <- rgamma(100, shape=1)
 gamma3 <- rgamma(1000, shape=1)
 gamma4 <- rgamma(5000, shape=1)
 }

 mean_gamma1 <- mean(gamma1)
 mean_gamma1
 mean_gamma2 <- mean(gamma2)
 mean_gamma2
 mean_gamma3 <- mean(gamma3)
 mean_gamma3
 mean_gamma4 <- mean(gamma4)
 mean_gamma4
```

I now intend to use the Method of Moments to derive empirically the values of a and b. I've seen gmm package, but it is not what I intended. I intended to do a step-by-step approach as if I were doing by hand. Do you know any package, or any method to do that? Or I would need to create my own function?

Comment: You should review your statistics text on what the central limit theorem says regarding the limiting distribution of  the mean of IID random variates drawn from _any_ distribution. You must have a mathematical statistics text, right?

Comment: @IRTFM I've revised, yes, it is what it is supposed, but I was looking for a package like fitdisplus

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to estimate `(a, b)` from `simulation1`, or are you trying to simulate 10K estimates of `(a, b)` each from 10 samples? IOW, what data are you starting with, and what type of output do you want?

Comment: @jblood94 I've changed my code, I was doing the wrong thing

Comment: @Anonymous ; your new code overwrites gamma* in each iteration of the loop ; i doubt this is what you want

Comment: this code is incorrect or rather does not do what you think it does. eg, why run a for-loop? also you end up with 4 numbers, ie gamma1:gamma4, what are their use? seems to me you are abit stuck on relaying exactly what you have

Comment: @user20650 my idea was to generate datasets representing T sample means from samples of fixed size n.

Comment: @Onyambu I wanted to try simulation for different numbers of sample means

Comment: well in that case your code does not do what you want. you need to rewrite your code

Comment: @Anonymous, Unfortunately, it is still not clear what you are trying to do. Again, what data are you starting with, and what type of output do you want?

Answer (score 1):

I think the "fitdistplus" package is what you are looking for:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
fitdist(simulation1, "gamma", method = "mme")



Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by matching moments 
Parameters:
      estimate
shape 9.223529
rate  9.217187
```

Comment: `simulation1` is assymptotically normal. its not gamma. Why are you fitting a gamma distribution?

Comment: @Onyambu I don't understand why you're saying it is assymptotically normal we're simulating gamma in rgamma

Comment: @Onyambu not with both parameters set to 1. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution or `hist(rgamma(n= 1000, shape = 1, rate = 1))`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik; the simulation is on the mean of the random gammas not the raw gamma sample

Comment: Ha, I was just reading the title and bits of code. :D

Comment: @RomanLuštrik when both parameters are set to 1 we have an exponential distribution. then the sampling distribution of the sample means is normal. CLT. it actually does not matter what the initial distribution is, the sample means are always normally distributed. CLT

Comment: @Anonymous because normal is the limiting distribution of the sample means. read on CLT

Comment: @Onyambu ; "sample means are **always** normally distributed." seems a bit strong ; the normality  depends on the original distribution and size of the samples

Comment: @user20650 Fair enough. what about *assuming a large enough size, the sampling distribution of the sample means will always be normal, regardless of the initial distribution.. *?

Comment: @Onyambu; that seems inline with the clt defn. And it fits with what the op illustrates: that the means from a sample size of 10 from the gamma(1,1)  is non-normal